# MySQL 8.0 Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' with empty password

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

On my Debian system, type
 `mysql -u root  -h localhost -P 3306`
It can login successfully:

```
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 213
Server version: 8.0.33 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Copyright (c) 2000, 2023, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

But when I start spring boot 2.5.3 with config like below in application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.jdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/mydb?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
```

produced exception like below:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:828) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:448) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
```

Comment: I strongly advise *not* running with a user called 'root'. For one thing, you can easily get locked out from the whole server doing that and it's a PITA to correct that. Create a new user with its own password

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget one property for password. Even though MySQL DB doesn't have any password you need to pass this property.

```
spring.datasource.jdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/mydb?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
```